# Cómo leer un paquete instalado en R

Tags: r, ggplot2

He instalado el paquete `ggplot2` en **R** pero a la hora de leerlo con la función `library(ggplot2)` me sale este error:

> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
>     there is no package called ‘colorspace’
>
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’

Por lo tanto no reconoce las funciones `ggplot()`, `qplot()`, etc. y no sé qué significa. Espero alguien me pueda ayudar.

Comment: No conozco R, pero por el mensaje, parece que `gplot2` tiene como dependencia `colorspace`.

Comment: Así parece. Ya instalé todas las dependencias del paquete, e incluso ésta de colorspace pero me sigue saliendo lo mismo :(

Comment: No me queda claro si intentaste previamente `install.packages("colorspace")`, y luego `install.packages("ggplot2")

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

Si te sigue saliendo el mismo problema tras instalar el paquete `colorspace` siento decir que realmente no tienes instalado el paquete.
De ser así, debería de darte problemas al cargarlo `library(colorspace)`. ¿Qué mensaje te aparece durante la instalación del pauqete? Puede que ahí esté el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes seguir el siguiente procedimiento y R no debería arrojarte ningún error:

```
install.packages("gtools", dependencies = TRUE)
```

Luego, cargas al paquete de dos formas:

```
requiere(ggplot2)
library(ggplot2)
```

Siendo Library más recomendada.